# Implement round using bind_rows(summarise)

Tags: r, tidyverse, gt

I am trying to round values on my table summary but round gets applied to the entire table instead of one section. How can I apply round() to just my summarized last row of the table? round() appears to be ignored. Example below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gt)

Data:
a <- structure(list(SampleDate = structure(c(15710, 15713, 15713, 
15710, 15710, 15713, 15713, 15710, 15708, 15713, 15712, 15708, 
15708, 15713, 15712, 15708), class = "Date"), year = c("2012", 
"2013", "2013", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013"), F = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 65, 0, 0), W = c(0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), S = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), LF = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), week = c("01", "02", "02", "01", 
"01", "02", "02", "01", "01", "02", "02", "01", "01", "02", "02", 
"01"), month = c("January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
"January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January"
)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
a

a %>% 
  group_by(year,SampleDate) |>
  summarise(F = sum(F), W = sum(W), S = sum(S), LF = sum(LF),count = n()) |> 
  ungroup() %>%  
  mutate_at(vars(year:SampleDate), funs(as.character(.))) %>%

  **#Only want to round to 2 decimals the Summed field below**
  bind_rows(summarise(year = 'Summed', SampleDate = '- - - - -', a, F = round(sum(F),2),
                      W = round(sum(W),2), S = round(sum(S),2), LF = round(sum(LF),2),
                      count = n()))  |> gt()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gt` has functions to create summary rows: `grand_summary_rows()`and
`summary_rows()`. You can control the decimals displayed with `fmt_numbers()`.
You can add another `grand_summary_rows()` call to add a second summary row
for a different set of columns. If you want to calculate several summary rows
for the same set of columns, you can `list()` several summary row specifications
in the `fns` argument.
In the example below I changed your `mutate_at()` to a
`mutate(across(...))` expression, which has superseded `mutate_at()` etc.

```r
upper_conf <- function(x) sum(x) + sd(x) * 1.64

a |>
  group_by(year, SampleDate) |>
  summarise(
    F = sum(F),
    W = sum(W),
    S = sum(S),
    LF = sum(LF),
    count = n()
  ) |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(across(year:SampleDate, as.character)) |>
  bind_rows()  |> 
  #select(-year) |> 
  gt() |> 
  # control decimals for non-summary rows here
  fmt_number(is.numeric, decimals = 2) |>
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = F:count,
    fns = list(label = "Total", fn = "sum"),
    # control decimals for summary rows here
    fmt = ~ fmt_number(., decimals = 2) 
  ) |> 
  grand_summary_rows(
    columns = F:LF,
    fns = list(
      list(label = "Std. Error", fn = "sd"),
      list(label = "Upper Conf. Int.", fn = "upper_conf")),
    # control decimals for summary rows here
    fmt = ~ fmt_number(., decimals = 2) 
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Till. Is it possible to add another row below Total? I want to add a std_error for columns F:LF.

Comment: You can add another `grand_summary_rows()` call to get a second summary row for a different set of columns. See my adjusted answer.

Comment: That looks great!!! One last thing @Till. If I add another grand_summary_rows(), How can I add or sum the values of `Total` and `std.Error` on that new and last row?

Comment: My understanding is that `grand_summary_rows()` only takes original rows of the `data.frame` into regard, no summary rows. I think that makes sense and don't understand why you'd want to further summarise these values.

Comment: I want to estimate the `Upper` confidence interval. Something like `Total + std.Error*1.64` for 90% confidence interval.

Comment: I understand that makes sense! If you want to calculate several summary rows for the same set of columns, you can `list()` several summary row specifications in the `fns` argument. No need to add another `grand_summary_rows()` call. I updated my answer. It now defines a function for the formula you specified and then uses it to create the additional summary row in the 2nd `grand_summary_rows()` call. If my answer has been helpful, please consider upvoting/accepting it. Thank you!

Comment: Really appreciate your help @Till. I have accepted your answer. You saved me a huge headache. I have been dragging this gt table for quite sometime now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that `round()` doesn't display digits if they are zero. For this we can usually use `sprintf`. I would do the formating with `gt::fmt_number()`. Here we can specify `columns` and `rows` and `decimals`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gt)

a |>
  group_by(year, SampleDate) |>
  summarise(across(c(F:LF), sum),
            count = n()) |> 
  ungroup() %>%  
  mutate(across(c(year:SampleDate), as.character)) |> 
  add_row(
    summarise(a,
              year = 'Summed',
              SampleDate = '- - - - -',
              across(c(F:LF), sum),
              count = n())
  ) |>
  gt() |> 
  fmt_number(
    columns  = c(F:LF),
    rows     = year == "Summed",
    decimals = 2
  )
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'year'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
```

Data from OP

```r
  a <- structure(list(SampleDate = structure(c(15710, 15713, 15713, 
                                               15710, 15710, 15713, 15713, 15710, 15708, 15713, 15712, 15708, 
                                               15708, 15713, 15712, 15708), class = "Date"), year = c("2012", 
                                                                                                      "2013", "2013", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
                                                                                                      "2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013"), F = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                     1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 22, 0, 0, 0, 65, 0, 0), W = c(0, 0, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), S = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), LF = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), week = c("01", "02", "02", "01", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "01", "02", "02", "01", "01", "02", "02", "01", "01", "02", "02", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "01"), month = c("January", "January", "January", "January", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "January", "January", "January", "January", "January", "January"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       )), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this @TimTeaFan. I like this but I also like the gt summary_rows way.